# Json schema of interface - serialization missing some fields

Tags: javascript, typescript

For this code, where I have an user defined interface and schema definition is guided.

```
type SchemaDefinition<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    type: { new(): unknown } //
    required?: boolean
  }
}

class Schema<T> {
  constructor(public schema: SchemaDefinition<T>) {}

  validate(obj: T): boolean {
    for (const prop of Object.keys(this.schema) as (keyof T)[]) {
      if (!(obj[prop] instanceof this.schema[prop].type)) return false
      if (this.schema[prop].required && obj[prop] == null) return false
    }

    return true
  }
}

interface IUser {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}
```

There are two schemas here. 1. for programming language specific container that is IUser interface 2. the one that I want to send it to backend that is composed by Schema object something like

```
new Schema<IUser>('users',
            {
                name: {type: Number, required: true},
                email: {type: String, required: true},
            });
```

now I am trying to serialize this Schema object to string using `JSON.stringify()` but `type` is skipped, how can I have it serialized or how can I translate this `IUser` into JSON schema in the best way in TS.

Edit:

I was able to retrieve the type name by doing something like this

```
const schemaRepresentation = {};
schemaRepresentation['title'] = this._name;
schemaRepresentation['additionalProperties'] = false;
schemaRepresentation['additionalProperties'] = false;

const properties = {};

for (const schemaKey in this.schema) {
  properties[schemaKey.toString()] = this.schema[schemaKey].datatype.name;
}

schemaRepresentation['properties'] = properties
```

if there is an array field in the interface - how do I get the type of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use values that are serializable to JSON because `String` and `Number` are functions, and therefore are not serializable.

For example, maybe you want to test the `typeof obj[prop]` for particular string.

```
type AllowedTypeNames = 'string' | 'number' | 'boolean'

type SchemaDefinition<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    type: AllowedTypeNames
    required?: boolean
  }
}
```

And `validate` would now look like:

```
  validate(obj: T): boolean {
    for (const prop of Object.keys(this.schema) as (keyof T)[]) {
      if (typeof obj[prop] !== this.schema[prop].type) return false
      // ^ check if the typeof the obj[prop] matches the schema.

      if (this.schema[prop].required && obj[prop] == null) return false
      // ^ check if the typeof the obj[prop] is required and present.
    }

    return true
  }
```

Which serializes fine:

```
const userSchema = new Schema<IUser>({
  name: { type: 'string', required: true },
  email: { type: 'string', required: true },
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(userSchema.schema))
// {"name":{"type":"string","required":true},"email":{"type":"string","required":true}}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=5#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-WGuDG021U06vUGujcE0HWoR+RMcG0Qx4dTQACSAFVjbRUVBGIQ4nM6M8ANxRRb0OARJ4sKvyJM44BQbj5la6eyMCDINQsvCWXP5myjflFksRBwxbARajlliUAA0UAdeQKEVj0Eqy+rulr09nkHnDdYq-XTrQW4GO73zZ2TYUOLOF1GHcEXbwpyBILBEJnYsiHnGAVygGs6yoPgAAF1FOXoCEoSofigAB6VCYlvZ8+lfRBLg-Wgvx-YF6FBcFx0nYCqFAqBKigdkR0EFD0JDMM6hfSRzjw647geM9XneAiiOtVkdiAA)

Comment: Thanks Alex. I was able to get the type by doing something in question (edited). your approach is good but it will not work for me as it limits the type. Now the question is how do I get the actual type of an array. +1

Comment: Please let me know if you think that is different question and deserves a new SO question.

Comment: That's a new question :) Also are you sure that you aren't just re-implementing https://json-schema.org/ ?

Comment: I looked at the ts implementation of json schema. it looks like the library form of this has to accept the `.ts` file as input - it is bit odd to ask user to supply that from my library user standpoint.